# Why is data.table not making a data.table from a table although data.frame does?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have following data and code:

```
mydf
  grp categ condition value
1   A     X         P     2
2   B     X         P     5
3   A     Y         P     9
4   B     Y         P     6
5   A     X         Q     4
6   B     X         Q     5
7   A     Y         Q     8
8   B     Y         Q     2
> 
> 
mydf = structure(list(grp = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), categ = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("X", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("P", 
    "Q"), class = "factor"), value = c(2, 5, 9, 6, 4, 5, 8, 2
    )), .Names = c("grp", "categ", "condition", "value"), out.attrs = structure(list(
    dim = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c("grp", "categ", 
    "condition")), dimnames = structure(list(grp = c("grp=A", 
    "grp=B"), categ = c("categ=X", "categ=Y"), condition = c("condition=P", 
    "condition=Q")), .Names = c("grp", "categ", "condition"))), .Names = c("dim", 
"dimnames")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

However, following works for data.frame but not for data.table:

```
> data.frame(with(mydf, table(grp, categ, condition)))
  grp categ condition Freq
1   A     X         P    1
2   B     X         P    1
3   A     Y         P    1
4   B     Y         P    1
5   A     X         Q    1
6   B     X         Q    1
7   A     Y         Q    1
8   B     Y         Q    1
> 
> data.table(with(mydf, table(grp, categ, condition)))
   V1
1:  1
2:  1
3:  1
4:  1
5:  1
6:  1
7:  1
8:  1
>
```

Am I making some mistake here or do I need to correct the data.table command to get other variables? It is highly unlikely that there is a bug here. With 2 variables it works all right:

```
> data.table(with(mydf, table(grp, categ)))
   categ grp N
1:     A   X 2
2:     B   X 2
3:     A   Y 2
4:     B   Y 2
> 
> 
> data.frame(with(mydf, table(grp, categ)))
  grp categ Freq
1   A     X    2
2   B     X    2
3   A     Y    2
4   B     Y    2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like `as.data.table(with(mydf, table(grp, categ, condition)))` works, though I'm not sure why just `data.table` isn't. My guess there is some method withing `data.frame` for `array`s which isn't present in `data.table` because in your first example it's an `array` compared to the second one. You could also do something like `Res <- setDT(data.frame(with(mydf, table(grp, categ, condition))))`, though it still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: `data.table` invokes `as.data.table` only for matrix or data.frame input. `data.frame` invokes `as.data.frame` also for other input.

Comment: you should file a bug report on github - there exists `as.data.table.table` but `data.table` doesn't delegate to it; fwiw I'd almost always use `as.data.table` to convert between types - it's usually faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in [commit #1760](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/93feeec4d6b66edfa0fa9088625bbdcce84a9e54) of data.table v1.9.5. Closes [#1043](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1043).